# Relation between the PDF of Y and of -Y

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

1.The pdf of variable $Y$ around the value $Y= - y$ , is equal to pdf of $-Y$, around the value $-Y = y.$

2.The pdf of variable $Y$ around the value $Y=y$ , is equal to pdf of $-Y$ around the value of $-Y = -y$.

The above statements hold always. Are there any mathematical proofs for these?

Answer (score 1):

In differential notation,
$$
f_Y(y) dy = P(Y\in (y,y+dy)).
$$
The trick is to look at the density as $Y$ belonging to this infinitesimal set, which makes it much easier to realize. Then
$$
\{ Y\in (y,y+dy)\} = \{-Y \in (-y-dy,-y)\}
$$
and the result follows.